# In pymongo while trying to use $add with update_many (and using $project) give 'Unknow: modifier': $project

Tags: mongodb, syntax, operators, pymongo

I am trying to sum 2 fields present in all the documents (favorite_count and retweet_count.) Then adding the result as a new field (or as an update):

```
filter = {'user.screen_name':author}
db.dwh_twt_tweets.update_many(filter= filter, update= {"$project":{
                                    'favorite_count':'$favorite_count',
                                    'retweet_count':'$retweet_count',
                                    'interactions':{"$add":
                                            ['$favorite_count','$retweet_count']}
                                                }
                                              }
                                            )
```

**I get:**

```
raise WriteError(error.get("errmsg"), error.get("code"), error)
 pymongo.errors.WriteError: Unknown modifier: $project
```

As an alternative I tried to substitute $project for $set but in that case the error I get is:

```
pymongo.errors.WriteError: The dollar ($) prefixed field '$add'    
in 'interactions.$add' is not valid for storage.
```

Comment: Just removed (filter=, update=), same errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"update_many" does not accept the same operators as "aggregate", please see the MongoDB Manual for the list of update operators that are currently implemented:

https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/

It is not possible to add two fields using update operators. You'll need to use "find" to fetch documents and add the fields in Python, then "$set" the fields with "update" to the sum.